# Display elements after parsing

Tags: json, swift, parsing, swiftui

Parsed `JSON`. Now I'm trying to display all this in a view.

But getting an error

```
Cannot find 'newsFeed' in scope
```

Here is my code

```
--- PostsController.swift ---

import Foundation

struct NewsFeed: Codable {
    var status:String = ""
    var totalResults:Int = 0
    var posts:[PostItem]
}

struct PostItem: Codable {
    var id:Int
    var title:String
    var link:String
    var date:String
    var category:String
    var thumbnail:String
    var excerpt:String
    var content:String
}

--- AppSwiftUIApp.swift ---

import SwiftUI

@main struct AppSwiftUIApp: App {

    init() {

        let urlString = "/json_news.json"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)

        guard url != nil else {
            return
        }

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

            if error == nil && data != nil {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    let newsFeed = try decoder.decode(NewsFeed.self, from: data!)
                    print(newsFeed.posts)
                } catch {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }

        }

        dataTask.resume()

    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }

}

--- MainPageView.swift ---

import SwiftUI

struct MainPageView: View {
    
    var body: some View {

        HeaderView()

        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {

            VStack() {

                ForEach(newsFeed.posts) { post in

                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                        Image(post.thumbnail)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)

                    }

                }

            }
            .padding(10)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)

        }

        FooterView()

    }
    
}
```

How I can pass a variable to a loop in a view so that I can use it?

Comment: Can you show this in code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform the json decoding in a class that conforms to ObservableObject and assign the result of the decoding to a @Published property

```
class NewsDecoder: ObservableObject {
    @Published var newsFeed: NewsFeed?

    init() {
        let urlString = "/json_news.json"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)

        guard url != nil else { return }

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    self.newsFeed = try decoder.decode(NewsFeed.self, from: data!)
                } catch {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }

        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

Then create an instance of that class in your view as an @ObservedObject and use the property in your ForEach

```
struct MainPageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var newsDecoder = NewsDecoder()
```

and access the data via `newsDecoder.newsFeed`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var newsDecoder = NewsDecoder()
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(newsDecoder.newsFeed?.posts ?? [], id: \.id) { feed in
            Text(feed.title)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a new error "Referencing initializer 'init(_:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'PostItem' conform to 'Identifiable'" when using foreach loop "ForEach(newsDecoder.newsFeed.posts) { post in"

Comment: This is easily solved by doing some research but you should be able to solve this by adding `id: \.id` to the ForEach header, please do not add more questions to your original question in the future

Comment: Sorry for more questions, but I new in Swift.. I steel have errors. What I need to do? Create new question?

Comment: @LexXy I added a short sample view code to my answer, if you still have some issue then yes you should ask a new question for that issue.