# How to call a getJSON function in another file in swift

Tags: swift, function

How can I call the below function in a different swift (view) file so that print statement (the one not in the comments (*/)) displays?

I have tried passing the function into a variable within the new view but this has not worked.

Would it also be easier to remove "do" statement entirely?

```
 func getJSON(){
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/68c39808d445fe90b1fe3d57b93ad9be20f796d2/public/data/latest/owid-covid-latest.json") else{
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){ (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            guard  let data = data else{
                return
            }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                //let decodedData = try decoder.decode([String:Country].self, from: data)
                //print (decodedData)
                let res = try decoder.decode([String:Country].self, from: data)
                let locations = Array(res.values).map { $0.location}
                let caseNumbers = Array(res.values).map{ $0.numberCheck}
                let vaccineNumbers = Array(res.values).map{ $0.vaccineCheck}
                
                /*Dual for loop
                 for (x, y) in zip(locations, caseNumbers) {
                    print("Country: ", x, " \t\t Yesterdays case numbers: ", y, ".")
                }*/
                
                ***for item in 0..<locations.count{
                    print("Country: ", locations[item], "\nCase Numbers 24hrs: ", caseNumbers[item], "\nNumber of People Fully Vaccinated: ", vaccineNumbers[item],"\n\n")***
                    
                    //Potential use in App when certain country is selected
                    //if locations[item] == "United Kingdom" {
                        //print(caseNumbers[item])}
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. What stops you from calling this function from another object and what do you mean with "print statement displays", do you want to use the result in your view?

Comment: I get the error Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols when calling the function in another view. I just want whats included in the print statement of the function to display in the new view

Comment: Apparently you are talking about SwiftUI. This information is crucial. You need the `Observable-/ObservedObject` pattern

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display elements after parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66562886/display-elements-after-parsing)